# List of objects Click event

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, object

I want to display and click objects in a html list on my webpage.
The creation of the html list including the object values (name) works well, also the click event. But I can not get the clicked object value (e.g. name). The result:

> (e.target.id) is ''(empty).

```
//Array of objects
let tierArray = {
  "name": data.Name,
  "geburtstag": data.Geburtstag,
  "geschlecht": data.Geschlecht,
  "idNummer": data["ID Nummer"],
  "imageIndexPath": data["Image Index Path"],
  "information": data.Information,
  "rasse": data.Rasse,
  "tierart": data.Tierart,
  "imTierheimSeit": data["im Tierheim seit"]
}

listOfTierObjects.push(tierArray);

//this works
for (let i = 0; i < listOfTierObjects.length; i++) {
  let row = `${listOfTierObjects[i].name}`;
  document.getElementById("tiereList").innerHTML += '<li>' + row + '</li>';
};

//The problem is here
document.getElementById("tiereList").onclick = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: You should add your full code...

Answer (score 3):

You aren't putting any `id` on the `li`, so `e.target.id` is `""`.

You haven't said what value you want to put there, but for instance you could put the index there if you wanted:

```
document.getElementById("tiereList").innerHTML += '<li id="' + index + '">' + row + '</li>';
```

...though I think I'd use a `data-*` attribute instead.

*(Note: Someone might tell you that `id="1"` [for example] isn't valid, but that's a common myth. An [`id`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) can be anything you want as long as it's unique and doesn't have any whitespace. The myth comes from the fact that a CSS ID selector can't start with an unescaped digit. But again, I wouldn't use `id` for this [what if you do this in two places?]. I'd use `...data-index="' + index + '"...` and `getAttribute("data-index"0` instead.)*

---

A couple of side notes:

- Using `+=` on `innerHTML` is not best practice. Either build up the full string in a variable and make a single assignment to `innerHTML`, or use `insertAdjacentHTML`, or use `createElement` instead.
- Even though `getElementById` is *very* fast, if you're going to use it in a loop for the same element, it's probably clearer to grab it to a variable and reuse the variable.
- `` let row = `${listOfTierObjects[i].name}`; `` when `listOfTierObjects[i].name` is a string can more simply be written `let row = listOfTierObjects[i].name;`.
- Rather than assigning to `.onclick`, I would suggest using `addEventListener`.
- Your current click handler will work, but if you had any child elements inside the `li` it wouldn't work reliably. Instead, use `const li = e.target.closest("li");` to reliably get the `li` element, even if the click is on a child element within the `li`.

More:

- [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Thank you very much T.J. Your proposal works fine for me :-)